# How to combine keyboard and mouse events to create a key mapping in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping, intellij-14

I want to add my own **key mappings** as combinations of keyboard and mouse events. Examples:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left double click
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse over
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + mouse over

How can I achieve this?

**Attempts:**

I went to Settings... > Appearance & Behavior > Keymap , but there are only 3 options:

- Add Keyboard Shortcut

  - I can press some keys, but IntelliJ doesn't recognize the mouse events here
- Add Mouse Shortcut

  - It works only for click / double click, keyboard is ignored
- Add Abbreviation

  [image]

I observed that some existing mappings already have such a combination where "left click" appears as "**Button1 Click**", but I don't know how to insert this text there because there is no Paste option and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is recognized as a key mapping, not as a command. I also tried to drag&drop some text, but it didn't work.

**Details**:

- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.1
- O.S.: Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enter a mouse shortcut, and simply use the modifier key when you click the message: *"Click here to enter mouse shortcut"*. The mouse button plus modifier should show up under the `Shortcut Preview` section of the dialog.

[image]

Comment: It works! I've just added a screen shot to be clearer for those who will encounter the same problem.